# How to run a function on the server alone (avoiding minimongo)?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to run this function inside of a `Meteor.methods` call:

```
geoSearch = function(long, lat, m) {
    return Sparks.find( { 'geo.coordinates' : 
        { $geoWithin : 
        { $centerSphere : 
            [ [ long, lat ] , m / 3959 ]
    } } } );
}
```

Minimongo does not recognize `$geoWithin`. Okay, so how do I run this query on the server alone (avoiding the client)? I tried moving this function to `/server` and invoking it from within the `Meteor.methods` call, but `geoSearch` was then `undefined`. Okay, so now, how do I invoke `geoSearch` from the client?

I'm sure there is an easy answer to my problem, I'm just not thinking of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the method on the server in a file under the `server` directory:

```
Meteor.methods({
  geoSearch: function (long, lat, m) {
    check(long, Number);
    check(lat, Number);
    check(m, Number);

    return Sparks.find...
  },

});
```

Then call it on the client:

```
Meteor.call('geoSearch', long, lat, m , function (error,result) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks to you both. I don't know why I forgot to use Meteor.call. I knew I was doing something wrong, lol. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `isSimulation` property from within a `Meteor.method` context :

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_issimulation

```
Meteor.methods({
  geoSearch: function(long, lat, m) {
    if(this.isSimulation){
      return;
    }
    return Sparks.find( { 'geo.coordinates' : 
      { $geoWithin : 
      { $centerSphere : 
        [ [ long, lat ] , m / 3959 ]
    } } } );
  }
});
```

Then from the client just `Meteor.call("geoSearch",...,function(error,result){...});` with the correct set of arguments and a callback to fetch the result, it will call the `$geoWithin` stuff only on the server and do nothing on the client.